# How can I call transfer function of a ERC20 token contract from another contract?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, history

I want to exchange token for a commodity using smart contracts. I have deployed my token contract address in my private block chain network. How should I create another contract that exchanges a commodity using the transfer function from the deployed token contract?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a balance in your Token contract T.
In order for your Commodity contract C to accept tokens and give the user the commodity in exchange, contract C would have to implement a function that accepts the tokens like follows:

```
function buyCommodityWithTokens(address _tokenAddress) public { 
  ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
  require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 100); // Assume the commodity being bought costs 100 tokens.

  commodityBalance[msg.sender] += 1; //We give the user the commodity

  token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, 100); // transfer the tokens

}
```

Please take into consideration that the function above is not taking security measures under consideration.

For this to work, the token owner must first call approve on the token contract to allow contract C to use tokens on his behalf.

Answer (score 0):

````
        address _token,
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint _amount
    )
        public
        returns (bool _success)
    {
        require(tokenTransferPermissions.isAuthorized(msg.sender));

        return ERC20(_token).transfer( _to, _amount);
    }
}```
````